# Does ember-cli compare favorably to linemanjs for front-end build management?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, linemanjs

I'm planning on building a web application with an EmberJS front-end that talks to a Flask-based RESTful API. I was originally excited to get going with lineman to help tackle the front-end, but recently I've been introduced to ember-cli. Ember-cli seems to be much more tightly integrated with EmberJS, though it appears to be less fleshed out than lineman.

Does anyone have experience with both lineman and ember-cli? If so, do you see a benefit of using one over another?